# Prove Gauss’s test:

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Prove Gauss’s test: If $$|\frac{c_{n + 1}}{c_n}| \leq 1 + \frac{a}{n},$$ where $a$ does not depend on $n$ and $a < -1$, then the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty c_n$ converges absolutely.

First we show $|\frac{c_{n + 1}}{c_n}|$ converges to $0$. Consider an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$.  Take $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ large enough so that $\frac{a}{\epsilon - 1} < n_0$. Consider an arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $n \geq n_0$. It follows that  $| \, |\frac{c_{n + 1}}{c_n}| - 0|  =  |\frac{c_{n + 1}}{c_n}| \leq 1 + \frac{a}{n} < 1 + \epsilon - 1 = \epsilon$. Thus 
$|\frac{c_{n + 1}}{c_n}|$ converges to $0$.

Since $|\frac{c_{n + 1}}{c_n}|$ converges to $0$, there exists an $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq n_1$ we have $|\frac{c_{n + 1}}{c_n}| < \frac{1}{2}$. Since $a < -1$ we know $|a| > 1$. Define $N =$ max$\{n_1, 1\}$, $M =???$ and $f(n) = n^{\frac{3}{2}}(1 - \frac{|a|}{n} - |\frac{c_{n + 1}}{c_n}|)$ for each $n$. Therefore $|\frac{c_{n + 1}}{c_n}| = 1 - \frac{|a|}{n} + \frac{f(n)}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$. 
\newline
Now since  $|\frac{c_{n + 1}}{c_n}|  \leq 1 + \frac{a}{n}$ we have $0 \leq 1 + \frac{a}{n} - |\frac{c_{n + 1}}{c_n}| = 1 - \frac{|a|}{n} - |\frac{c_{n + 1}}{c_n}|$ since $a < 0$ since $a < -1$. Consider an arbitrary $n \geq N$. It follows that $|f(n)| = |n^{\frac{3}{2}}(1 - \frac{|a|}{n} - |\frac{c_{n + 1}}{c_n}|)| = n^{\frac{3}{2}}(1 - \frac{|a|}{n} - |\frac{c_{n + 1}}{c_n}|) $

How do I show $ n^{\frac{3}{2}}(1 - \frac{|a|}{n} - |\frac{c_{n + 1}}{c_n}|) \leq M$ for some $M$? I know $ n^{\frac{3}{2}}(1 - \frac{|a|}{n} - |\frac{c_{n + 1}}{c_n}|) \leq  2n^{\frac{3}{2}}(1 - \frac{|a|}{n})$ But I don't think that helps since I need all the $n's$ to be to a power $< 1$ in order to converge.

link to Gauss’s test:https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~rdhough/mat141-fall16/lectures/lecture19.pdf